# PIL image to array (numpy array to array) - Python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, python-imaging-library

I have a .jpg image that I would like to convert to Python array, because I implemented treatment routines handling plain Python arrays.

It seems that PIL images support conversion to numpy array, and according to the documentation I have written this:

```
from PIL import Image
im = Image.open("D:\Prototype\Bikesgray.jpg")
im.show()

print(list(np.asarray(im)))
```

This is returning a list of numpy arrays. Also, I tried with

```
list([list(x) for x in np.asarray(im)])
```

which is returning nothing at all since it is failing.

How can I convert from PIL to array, or simply from numpy array to Python array?

Comment: have you tried the numpy array's `tolist()` method?

Comment: We call them **lists**, not arrays, for the native Python data type. "Array" means either the numpy thing, or else what you get from the `array` standard library module, or some other third-party library.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

I think what you are looking for is:

```
list(im.getdata())
```

or, if the image is too big to load entirely into memory, so something like that:

```
for pixel in iter(im.getdata()):
    print pixel
```

from [PIL documentation](http://effbot.org/imagingbook/image.htm#tag-Image.Image.getdata):

> getdata
>
> im.getdata() => sequence
>
> Returns the contents of an image as a sequence object containing pixel
>   values. The sequence object is flattened, so that values for line one
>   follow directly after the values of line zero, and so on.
>
> Note that the sequence object returned by this method is an internal
>   PIL data type, which only supports certain sequence operations,
>   including iteration and basic sequence access. To convert it to an
>   ordinary sequence (e.g. for printing), use list(im.getdata()).

Comment: looks good in doc but still not working. i had to abort process. any idea? thanks

Comment: try with a smaller image first, just to see that you are getting the desired result, then you can handle the memory problems caused by trying to load the entire image into a list and print it.

Comment: Maybe instead of converting it to a list just go over it using an iterator. see my edit

Comment: thanks for update. i wish i could have the corresponding intensity matrix (2D array), so i tried `for x in im_array:
    
 matrix.append(list(x))
 print matrix` which want me to abort python.exe again

Comment: now this is obvious: problem is that a PIL image converts to a 3d numpy array (or plain Python array). also, i dont have the intensity matrix i want in the end. i guess this is because PIL images are encoded in a RGB fashion, with 3 dimensions. would need to map this encoding to a representation with unique reprensentation for each pixel. do you have a hint (will look at doc in the meantime) ? thanks

Comment: Try this :) `int(sum(map(lambda x: x[0] * x[1], zip(pixel,(0.299,0.587,0.114)))))`

Comment: these are your favorite coefficients, right ? ;  ) what about PIL `.convert('L')` ? converts to grayscale, right ?

Comment: @octoback Correct, `.convert('L')` converts to grayscale.

Comment: Just a small note but I don't think you actually need to use iter()... When you use a for loop the __iter__ method will be called automatically.

Answer (score 23):

I highly recommend you use the `tobytes` function of the `Image` object. After some timing checks this is much more efficient.

```
def jpg_image_to_array(image_path):
  """
  Loads JPEG image into 3D Numpy array of shape 
  (width, height, channels)
  """
  with Image.open(image_path) as image:         
    im_arr = np.fromstring(image.tobytes(), dtype=np.uint8)
    im_arr = im_arr.reshape((image.size[1], image.size[0], 3))                                   
  return im_arr
```

The timings I ran on my laptop show

```
In [76]: %timeit np.fromstring(im.tobytes(), dtype=np.uint8)
1000 loops, best of 3: 230 µs per loop

In [77]: %timeit np.array(im.getdata(), dtype=np.uint8)
10 loops, best of 3: 114 ms per loop
```

```

Comment: `np.fromstring` is deprecated. Use `np.frombuffer` instead.

Answer (score 7):

Based on [zenpoy's answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13550527/3798217):

```js
import Image
import numpy

def image2pixelarray(filepath):
    """
    Parameters
    ----------
    filepath : str
        Path to an image file

    Returns
    -------
    list
        A list of lists which make it simple to access the greyscale value by
        im[y][x]
    """
    im = Image.open(filepath).convert('L')
    (width, height) = im.size
    greyscale_map = list(im.getdata())
    greyscale_map = numpy.array(greyscale_map)
    greyscale_map = greyscale_map.reshape((height, width))
    return greyscale_map
```

Answer (score 3):

I use numpy.fromiter to invert a 8-greyscale bitmap, yet no signs of side-effects

```py
import Image
import numpy as np

im = Image.load('foo.jpg')
im = im.convert('L')

arr = np.fromiter(iter(im.getdata()), np.uint8)
arr.resize(im.height, im.width)

arr ^= 0xFF  # invert
inverted_im = Image.fromarray(arr, mode='L')
inverted_im.show()
```