# Open images with PIL in pycharm

Tags: python, pycharm, python-imaging-library

I try to open tif image in pycharm and convert the image to numpy array

```
from PIL import Image
import numpy as np
im =Image.open('shua.tif',mode='r')
x = np.array(im)
print x
```

but it prints the output like this:

```
 <PIL.TiffImagePlugin.TiffImageFile image mode=RGB size=128x128 at 0x2F05A88>
```

but if I run the code via console it works fine.

Comment: you should use : `list(im.getdata())` : http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550376/pil-image-to-array-numpy-array-to-array-python

Comment: thanks but it dos'ent works. the problem is that my code work on console but not in Pycharm

Comment: any answer on this?

Answer (score 10):

Here you go:

```
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
import PIL

img = PIL.Image.open(...)
plt.imshow(img)
plt.show()
```

Comment: unfortunately, the resolution is really bad when using this method.. anyway to fix this ?