# How convert image to an array in python

Tags: python, arrays, image, numpy, scipy

I want to convert image (.jpg) to binary array. Because I have to use this array to my scrambler operating on it saved in file. Which library and and functions should I use?

Comment: Check out this link: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550376/pil-image-to-array-numpy-array-to-array-python

Comment: Possible duplicate of [PIL image to array (numpy array to array) - Python](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13550376/pil-image-to-array-numpy-array-to-array-python)

Comment: OP mentioned in a comment that he's using Python 3.6.4, so PIL won't actually help him, and I'm guessing that he'll need a Python 3 alternative.

Comment: @ZeBirdeh Hopefully he's going to incorporate that information into the post because, as it stands, the question needs work.

Answer (score 1):

You should take a look at the [openCV library](https://docs.opencv.org/3.0-beta/doc/py_tutorials/py_gui/py_image_display/py_image_display.html).

```
import cv2
img = cv2.imread('image.jpg', flags=cv2.IMREAD_COLOR)
```

Comment: ModuleNotFoundError: No module named 'cv2' ||  I can't use cv2, there is no option to import it. I have Python3.6.4

Comment: You should install the opencv module first for this to work. https://pypi.org/project/opencv-python/

Answer (score 1):

You can use the python library: PIL & numpy. Click [here](https://www.comp.nus.edu.sg/~cs5240/image.html) to learn more about image handling in python.

```
import numpy
import PIL

img = PIL.Image.open("foo.jpg").convert("L")
imgarr = numpy.array(img)
```

Answer (score 0):

- You can use this code to convert your image to array

```
# Import the necessary libraries 
from PIL import Image 
from numpy import asarray 
  
  
# load the image and convert into  
# numpy array 
img = Image.open('test.jpg') 
arraydata = asarray(img) 
  
# data 
print(arraydata)
```